# rails auditor gem - audits.user_id may not be NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I'm using the auditor gem to track changes in my models, and I find it quite annoying that whenever I'm trying to work from console I get this error (I guess user_id is taken from current_user and it's not associated).

I'm trying to create some objects for development, and just have to do it from the dbconsole every time..

I use 'audit(:create, :update, :destroy)' and not 'audit!'.

Does anyone knows if I can suppress these errors or disable the user_id null check? (I don't care that if in production I run console and create an object, I'll have a NULL there).

Many thanks,
Zach

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Problem was that I didn't have any attr_accessible declared. Read this: https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited#gotchas

edit:
Also, I had to define a method for current_user:

```
def current_user
  User.find_by_username 'root'
end
```

Comment: Tried that, no luck... Where did you define the currnet_user method? I've tried to put it in the model and also to define in the console.I have attr_accessible for my model fields, but the error I get is for the insert statement to audits table (client_id is null there and as far as I understand, that's the client_id of the user that makes the change)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set current_user to a user object before your audit work?

```
current_user = User.first
...your other code here
```

Comment: Tried.. I still get the same error. it probably doesn't get my current_user variable..